# Laravel - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, gateway

I encountered a very strange problem today. Well, he gets the error

> 502 Bad Gateway

All the time when there are several requests on the page. I searched the entire Internet and no solution from the ready helped me.

PHP-FPM LOG:

```
[20-Nov-2018 19:00:43] NOTICE: Terminating ...    
[20-Nov-2018 19:00:43] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!   
[20-Nov-2018 19:00:57] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 229   
[20-Nov-2018 19:00:57] NOTICE: ready to handle connections     
[20-Nov-2018 19:00:57] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

Comment: It could be the web server. Check the server logs. I see this more often with nginx when something is timing out or a bad configuration.

Comment: It means? Which logs?

Comment: It can be any number of things. Check the laravel logs in `storage/logs`, and check your webserver logs. If you're using linux, nginx would be in `/var/log/nginx`, apache would be in `/var/log/apache`, `/var/log/apache2`, or `/var/log/httpd`.  Just check your system to find out where the logs might be.

Comment: I checked all logs. There is nothing in them that is just strange. I think that these requests are limited by php.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using php7.3 and Homestead 8.0.0. After digging around I found this solution, which has worked.

```sh
sudo phpdismod xdebug
sudo service php7.3-fpm reload
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1045

Answer (score 0):

I've fix it by changing my php version from "MultiPHP Manager" in my cPanel.